# I'm a beginner - trying to shorten this code

Tags: vba, excel

I want a Yes/No in column C to set off a series of things in columns d - h:
If no cell is grey and displays N/A
And If yes be yellow and either a dropdown appears or users can enter data depending on the column

Am I going about this the right way or can I do this more efficiently? (And sorry if there's an obvious answer - I'm a true beginner)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Cell As Range
If Target.Column = 3 Then
    Set Cell = Target.Offset(0, 1)
    If Len(Target.Value) = 0 Then
        Cell.ClearContents
        Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
        Cell.Value = vbNullString
    Else
        If Target.Value = "Yes" Then
            Cell.ClearContents
            Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 36

        ElseIf Target.Value = "No" Then
            Cell.ClearContents
            Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 16
            Cell.Value = "N/A"
        End If
    End If
End If

If Target.Column = 3 Then
Set Cell = Target.Offset(0, 2)
    If Len(Target.Value) = 0 Then
        Cell.ClearContents
        Cell.Validation.Delete
        Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
        Cell.Value = vbNullString
Else
        If Target.Value = "Yes" Then
            Cell.ClearContents
            Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 36
            With Cell.Validation
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=Numbers"
            End With
ElseIf Target.Value = "No" Then
            Cell.ClearContents
            Cell.Validation.Delete
            Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 16
            Cell.Value = "N/A"
        End If
    End If
End If

If Target.Column = 3 Then

Set Cell = Target.Offset(0, 3)
```

NOTE: This is for column F but I need the same for Column G too

```
If Len(Target.Value) = 0 Then
        Cell.ClearContents
        Cell.Validation.Delete
        Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
        Cell.Value = vbNullString
Else
        If Target.Value = "Yes" Then
            Cell.ClearContents
            Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 36
            With Cell.Validation
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=Numbers"
            End With
ElseIf Target.Value = "No" Then
            Cell.ClearContents
            Cell.Validation.Delete
            Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 16
            Cell.Value = "N/A"
        End If
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I think [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is the place for this

Comment: It took me about 13 days, but I think you're right!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that for not repeating the code. You will specify the column to check in the Union Range, and check just one time if intersect that range.

Then if u have to delete specify cell offset, just add it to the if where Cell.Validation will delete cell

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
    Dim rngToCheck As Range
    Set rngToCheck = Union(ActiveSheet.Columns(3), ActiveSheet.Columns(4))
    If Not Intersect(target, rngToCheck) Is Nothing Then
        FormatCell target
    End If
End Sub

Sub FormatCell(ByRef target As Range)
    Dim offRange As Integer, cell As Range

    For offRange = 1 To 3
        Set cell = target.Offset(0, offRange)
        If Len(target.Value) = 0 Then
            cell.ClearContents
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
            cell.Value = vbNullString
        Else
            If target.Value = "Yes" Then
                cell.ClearContents
                cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 36
                If offRange = 2 Then
                    With cell.Validation
                        .Delete
                        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                        Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=Numbers"
                    End With
                End If
            ElseIf target.Value = "No" Then
                If offRange = 2 Then cell.Validation.Delete
                cell.ClearContents
                cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 16
                cell.Value = "N/A"
            End If
        End If
    Next offRange
End Sub
```

An advice, never code in the Events, just let the event call another function passing the necessary thing to that function, it should be clear, and you have to specify in the function what you want to do!

You can read my code like that:

Worksheet change?.
Create a range to check, we have to watch column 3 and 4.

Check if the changed cell is in that range (intersect method).

If it is, pass the range to the FormatCell function for let him to do what he want to do.